# Place holder for form dropdown select type?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, magento

how do i add a "Please select an option" to be the default shown option in a drop down select box in a form.

I'm modifying a magento module adding in some new input fiends on the frontend that saves it to a table in magento's database. the form works correctly saving the information to the database but it always shows the 1st item from the array used to list the options. so if the user doent change the option, then array [0] will be added to the database. i want to add a place holder that wont be added to the database, so it will prompt the user to select an option.

this is the information that is called:

```
$fields[] = array(
        'name'     => 'vehicle_make',
        'label'    => Mage::helper('sublogin')->__('Make'),
        'required' => true,
        'type'     => 'select',
        'style'    => 'width:100px',
        'cssclass' => '',
        'options'  => array ("Acura", "Alfa Romeo","Audi", "BMW", "Buickm", "Cadillac", "Chevrolet", "Chrysler", "Dodge", "FIAT", "Ford", "GMC", "Honda", "Hyundai", "Infiniti", "Jaguar", "Jeep", "Kia", "Land Rover", "Lexus", "Lincoln", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes-Benz", "MINI", "Mitsubishi", "Nissan", "Porsche", "Ram", "Scion", "Smart", "Subaru", "Suzuki", "Toyota", "Volkswagen", "Volvo", "Yamaha"),
    );
```

this is what is used to show the input field:

```
if ($formField['type'] == 'select' || $formField['type'] == 'multiselect')
                    {
                        $selectedOptions = $sublogin->getData($formField['name']);
                        $selectedOptions = explode(',', $selectedOptions);
                        ?>
                        <select 
                            <?php echo ($formField['type'] == 'multiselect')?"multiple=multiple":""; ?> 
                            id="<?php echo $formField['name'] ?>" 
                            name="<?php echo ($formField['type'] == 'multiselect')? $formField['name'].'[]':$formField['name'] ?>">
                        <?php foreach ($formField['options'] as $optionValue => $optionLabel) {
                            $selected = '';
                            if (in_array($optionValue, $selectedOptions))
                                $selected = 'selected';                             

                            echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$optionValue.'">'.$optionLabel.'</option>';
                        } ?>
                        </select>
```

[image: vehicle make]

Comment: you ask a question about a `select`, but you provide the code for an `input`?

Comment: @Sean, but isnt it considered a select input field? i did make i mistake in the 1st codes i shown, corrected now.

Comment: For select box you just place the first item of dropdown as "Select an Option".

Comment: If you want `Please select an option` as the default/first value, have you tried adding it to your code - `'options'  => array ("Please select an option", "Acura", "Alfa Romeo", ...`?

Comment: @Sean I'm sure that method would make it show as the default option, but it doesnt achieve my requirement. if i just place it into the array means it will save it to the database like any other option. I want it to be like a NULL place holder, so if the user doesnt select an option it propts then "This field required, please select an option".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your above code

```
<select 
                            <?php echo ($formField['type'] == 'multiselect')?"multiple=multiple":""; ?> 
                            id="<?php echo $formField['name'] ?>" 
                            name="<?php echo ($formField['type'] == 'multiselect')? $formField['name'].'[]':$formField['name'] ?>">
                        <?php foreach ($formField['options'] as $optionValue => $optionLabel) {
                            $selected = '';
                            if (in_array($optionValue, $selectedOptions))
                                $selected = 'selected';                             

                            echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$optionValue.'">'.$optionLabel.'</option>';
                        } ?>
                        </select>
```

add that default option before foreach like this

```
<select 
                            <?php echo ($formField['type'] == 'multiselect')?"multiple=multiple":""; ?> 
                            id="<?php echo $formField['name'] ?>" 
                            name="<?php echo ($formField['type'] == 'multiselect')? $formField['name'].'[]':$formField['name'] ?>">
//added this line of code
                            <option name="please-select" value="100">Please select an option</option>
                        <?php foreach ($formField['options'] as $optionValue => $optionLabel) {
                            $selected = '';
                            if (in_array($optionValue, $selectedOptions))
                                $selected = 'selected';                             

                            echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$optionValue.'">'.$optionLabel.'</option>';
                        } ?>
                        </select>
```

You can use any value and name for this. Now use can use javascript to validate it.

Hope this helps.